# How to display value only once based on the boolean value in a list of elements in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, loops, boolean

In the below code based on the temp boolean value I need to display one label inside the loop, I have to show the label only once if the temp is set to true, no matter how many true booleans are there, the text has to display only once. but the below code displays 3 times since 3 temp booleans are set to true. Can someone please help me with how to do this?

```
import React from 'react';
const MyComponent = () => {
const data = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Item 1', temp : false },
    { id: 2, name: 'Item 2', temp : false },
    { id: 3, name: 'Item 3', temp : true },
    { id: 4, name: 'Item 4', temp : true },
    { id: 5, name: 'Item 5', temp : true },
    { id: 6, name: 'Item 6', temp : false },
    { id: 7, name: 'Item 7', temp : false },
    { id: 8, name: 'Item 8', temp : false },
];
return (
    <div>
    {
        data.map((item) => {
        return (
        <div key={item.id}>
        <span>{item.name}</span>
        { item.temp ?
        <span> temp label displayed </span>
        : null
    }
    </div>
    );
})}
</div>
);
};
export default MyComponent;
```

Output:
[image]

Note: I cant hardcode any of the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use some kind of **flag** to check if you need to render the temp label.

I solved it like this, I added a `useRef` to be the flag and use this ref to keep track whether or not we've already rendered a **temp label**.

```js
import React, { useRef } from "react";

const MyComponent = () => {
  const data = [
    { id: 1, name: "Item 1", temp: false },
    { id: 2, name: "Item 2", temp: false },
    { id: 3, name: "Item 3", temp: true },
    { id: 4, name: "Item 4", temp: true },
    { id: 5, name: "Item 5", temp: true },
    { id: 6, name: "Item 6", temp: false },
    { id: 7, name: "Item 7", temp: false },
    { id: 8, name: "Item 8", temp: false },
  ];

  const flag = useRef(null);

  return (
    <div>
      {data.map((item, idx) => {
        // set flag if the item is a temp item and the flag has not been set yet
        if (item.temp && flag.current === null) flag.current = idx;

        return (
          <div key={item.id}>
            <span>{item.name}</span>
            {flag.current === idx ? <span> temp label displayed </span> : null}
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
export default MyComponent;
```

Live preview [a codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-brattain-xr99h2)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Ruben, This worked like a charm. I was struggling more than 3 days for this, I tried the same flag logic but was not doing it in a proper way.
Many thanks